# Can you pull Data from a row based on date

Tags: ampscript, lookup, content

I am trying to lookup a row of data based on a date and I am getting an error when I try to pull content based on the date column event if I put in the actual data instead of using the "Now()" date function. Below is the AMPscript I am using to test the data pull, I am looking for any insights or possible solutions.

Thanks!

```
**%%[
var @lookupValue, @numRowsToReturn, @rows, @rowCount 

set @lookupValue = "Now()"
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("ent.dailyemailcopy",1,"subject_line asc","date", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

var @row, @preheader, @subject_line

set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
set @preheader = field(@rows,"preheader")
set @subject_line = field(@rows,"subject_line")

]%%

Row %%=v(@i)=%%, Pre Header is %%=v(@preheader)=%%, Subject Line is %%=v(@subject_line)=%%

%%[

next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%**
```

Data is setup in a CSV as follows:

[image: DE CSV]

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the quotes around the `Now()` function.

```
set @lookupValue = Now()
```

Keep in mind the `Now()` function will return a date with the time, so you'll need to strip the time portion off with the [**format()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/format/) function if your data extension isn't precise:

```
set @lookupValue = Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Here's some sample code:

```
%%[
var @lookupValue
set @lookupValue = Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-dd")
]%%
<br>now(): %%=Now()=%%
<br>Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-dd"): %%=v(@lookupValue)=%%
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: I tried the set @lookupValue = Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-dd") to pull and I get the following error when i try to previw: "There was an error building your preview."

Comment: Updated my answer with a sample.

Comment: Did you remove the quotes around your now() function?

Comment: I did, that didn't show an error but it did not pull any data. it returned with "No rows found". I have added SS for my Data above

Comment: This is a example Data DE with dummy content

Comment: What do the dates look like when you view them in the data extension?  If your DE dates have times, then you'll need to create a special lookupDate column (that doesn't include a timestamp) in your DE and use a query to populate it.  If you can't do that, then you can do a full blown [AMPScript API retrieve on the Data Extension](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/retrieving_rows_from_a_data_extension_using_ampscript_and_the_web_service_api/).

Comment: If you use the Web Service API, then you can use SimpleFilterPart and ComplexFilterParts with [boolean operators](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/simpleoperators/) to retrieve ranges of rows.

Comment: It does have a timestamp on it that is probably why its not returning any data.

Comment: I can use this to populate certain content in the email based on date correct?

Comment: Sure thing.  Even the subject line.

Comment: Working with this is there somewhere to see an example of this (AMPScript API retrieve on the Data Extension) in use?